# how to check and extract credit card number using regex from a phrase in java

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a String

> "my credit card number is 4444444444444448, and bla bla bla..".

How can I extract the number from entire string using regex.

The regex pattern for VISA I used is

```
"^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14})$"
```

but don't know how to use it with bulky string. I am newbie to regex.

Comment: `\\b\\d{15,16}\\b` will cover most of the credit cards

Comment: You can see for help:http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/11/18/java-regex-validate-credit-card-numbers/

Comment: @Akshada Gaikwad have a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) and [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx all,
I tried following code and it worked greatly as I wanted.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String ccPattern = "((?:(?:\\d{4}[- ]){3}\\d{4}|\\d{16}))(?![\\d])";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ccPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("My credit card number is 4444-4444-4444-4448.");
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Pattern matches");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Does not matches");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14})");
    // get a matcher object
    String v = "my visa 4444444444444448 number 4444444444444448";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(v);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Match number " + count);
        System.out.println("start(): " + m.start());
        System.out.println("end(): " + m.end());
    }
}
```